# Getting the component type from a object in craftyjs

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

Let's say I have a code like the following.

```
Crafty.c("SomeType",{//do something... });
var obj=Crafty.e("SomeType");
```

Can anyone tell me whether there is a function to check the type of the object?

Ex:

```
Crafty.isComponent(obj,"SomeType")==true
```

or

```
Crafty.getComponents(obj)=="SomeType"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah found out from the Crafty.js file that there is a .has() function to check for a component. :)

```
    /**@
    * #.has
    * @comp Crafty Core
    * @sign public Boolean .has(String component)
    * Returns `true` or `false` depending on if the
    * entity has the given component.
    *
    * For better performance, simply use the `.__c` object
    * which will be `true` if the entity has the component or
    * will not exist (or be `false`).
    */
```